# Simulate a basic computer

Tags: windows, simulation

I need a program to develop a GUI Windows application that simulates a basic computer. The interface needs to have the following fields:

- The starting address of the shown memory (Input/output)
- Memory window showing 16 words at a time starting from the "starting address" (input/output)
- Register Window showing the contents of all registers used (input/output)
- ALU window showing the two inputs and the output (output)
- Flag window showing all three flags (input/output)
- Instruction address window (input/output)
- Instruction window showing the assembly language of the instruction at   the given "instruction address" (input/output)
- Time window showing the current cycle number (can be reset to 0)
- Truce button to simulate one cycle.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, ella! ["The best" is always subjective](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/157/185) and rather should be avoided (nobody will ask for "the worst", right?) Though Windows programming is not exactly my area of expertise, it looks like you've missed some other important details here we'll need to give good recommendations, e.g. which does need those fields: the prog you're writing, or the prog your looking for? What other requirements? Please check with [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for possible improvements.

Comment: The question's title and the first sentence contradict each other. Are you asking for the software which simulates the computer, as the title says? Or are you going to develop it yourself, as the first sentence says?  Your first sentence says " need a program to develop a GUI Windows application that simulates a basic computer", which, in fact, just means that you need to develop  Windows program and many IDEs will help you to do that. Why not use MS Visual Studio?

Comment: Thank you , I need the program to be already made but i choose the specification , i don't want to write a code i just want to enter the description of the system and it be modeled  .